# drf-spectacular: how to show the primary key in examples section of Swagger

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, drf-spectacular

I'm trying to show the primary key in the examples section of Swagger, I'm using [drf-spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and my code looks like:

Serializers.py

```
class SerializerExample(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id','name')
```

Views.py

```
class BooksBulkUpdate(APIView):
    @extend_schema(
        request=SerializerExample(many=True),
        responses={200:''},
    )
    def put(self, request, format=None):
        with transaction.atomic():
            for data in request.data:
                book = Book.objects.get(pk=data['id'])
                serializer = SerializerExample(book, data=data, partial=True)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                else:
                    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response()
```

Only the name field is showing:

[image]

The only solution that I found was using an [inline serializer](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.utils.inline_serializer) which is not the ideal solution because if I update my book serializer I'd have to remember to update also this inline serializer. I wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: The `id` is a "read_only" field, by default, which is not supposed to be altered during API requests. Even though if you send the payload with `id` field, the DRF will gracefully ignore it. With that said, ***there is no use representing the `id` in your swagger spec or sending it in the payload***

Comment: My endpoint does not alter the id, but I need the id to know which book to update. My endpoint updates a batch of books at the same time.

Comment: So, you are planning to accept the `id` value at the DRF side?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question to show a more detailed example of the view.py code

Comment: IMHO, `inline serializer` is the best solution for you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I need this for the exact same reason.

Comment: @DustinWyatt I ended up using `request=inline_serializer(...)`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK swagger shows input request schema.

For example, you want to add new `person` and your model is

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

So you allowed to set only `name` parameter

Even if you post

```json
{
  "id": "someUUID",
  "name": "NAME",
}
```

`id` will be ignored and Django create it automatically by own logic (because it is read only)

But you can set `id` field writeable:

```py
class SerializerExample(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.UUIDField(write_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id','name')
```

`write_only=True` means that field will be active when you saving new data and receiving `id` from request json.
In opposite `read_only=True` will print `id` field at response (if you trying get data) but ignore it when you saving new data.

So you try to describe API for data adding, and of course that is not allow to set `id` field in request json.

Not sure if this theory applicable to your case, but hope that will be helpful.

Comment: I understand what you mean but the reason why I need to receive the id in the body is because my endpoint that looks like /books/bulk_update what does is to update a batch of books at the same time, instead of calling multiple times to something like /books/<id> . Probably there are better ways of doing a bulk update but this is the reason why I need to show my API users that they need to add the id in the body.